# Global scope object with constructor

Tags: object, constructor, global, new-operator

I've created a function that iterates thru some data and creates several objects to hold that data. Everything works as expected, but i now realize that these objects aren't accessible outside the function where they were created. Is it easy to change this? I'd prefer to have the objects still being created inside this function if possible.
I am using the new- keyword when creating the objects.

```js
function createObjets(recData); {
// Find all sensors
  let sensors = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < recData.length; i++) {
    let foundId = recData[i].split(",")[2];
    if (!sensors.includes(foundId)) {
      sensors.push(foundId);
    }

// Create an object for each sensor id
  for (let s = 0; s < sensors.length; s++) {
    sensor[s] = new sensor();
    sensor[s].setData(recData, sensors[s]);
  }
}  

function sensor() {
  this.setData = function(data, sensor) {
  // Extracts data for current sensor id
  this.id     = sensor;
  this.date   = [];
  this.time   = [];
  this.temp   = [];
  this.rh     = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Loop thru all readings and store data only for current sensor
    if (data[i].split(",")[2] == this.id) {
      this.date.push(data[i].split(",")[0]);
      this.time.push(data[i].split(",")[1]);
      this.temp.push(data[i].split(",")[3]);
      this.rh.push(data[i].split(",")[4]);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the array "sensor" outside the function I was able to make it global. The reason I didn't realize this before posting the question was that I by mistake tried to call the object too early, before createObjects had been invoked..